# Why web socket connection is finishing without establishing a connection on the AWS instance even with a secure connection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, socket.io, socket.io-client

The web socket connection is finishing without establishing a connection on the AWS instance even with a secure connection.

Working perfectly fine on my local and staging environments.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.domain.co:3004/socket.io/?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY5N2Q3ZmI1ZGNkZThjZD....ZDtBXHGAXymsdupg9KC8hMkc63pc9A_SKxDRGloUC5qkA&EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: 

Error: websocket error
    at s.value (transport.js:38:37)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (websocket.js:80:37)
```

**React Code:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    if (isInitialised && isAuthenticated && token && userUuid) {
      const socket = socketIO(url, { query: { token }, transports: ['websocket'], secure: true });
      socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
        console.log(reason);
        if (reason === "io server disconnect" || reason === "io client disconnect") {
          // the disconnection was initiated by the server or client, you need to reconnect manually
          socket.connect();
        }
        // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
      });
      socket.on("connect_error", (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
      socket.emit("registerForRapidStatus", userUuid);
      socket.on("rapidIdStatus", (data) => {
        setSocketData(data);
        const { isVerified, rapidVerificationAttempts } = data;
        updateUserProfile({ ...user, rapidIsVerified: isVerified, rapidVerificationAttempts });
      });
      return () => {
        socket.off('rapidIdStatus');
        socket.close();
      };
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isInitialised, isAuthenticated, userUuid]);
```

**NodeJs Express Code:**

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: { origins: [process.env.SOCKET_ORIGINS] }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  listenToSocketEvent(socket)
  console.log("Socket is connected.");
});

var socketsForRapid = new Map();

const inComingEvents = {
  registerForRapidStatus: "registerForRapidStatus"
}

const listenToSocketEvent = (socket) => {
  const eventNames = Object.values(inComingEvents);
  eventNames.forEach((eventName) => {
    socket.on(eventName, (data) => {
      switch (eventName) {
        case inComingEvents.registerForRapidStatus:
          registerUserForRapidStatus(data, socket)
          break;
      }
    });
  })
}

const registerUserForRapidStatus = (userUuid, socket) => {
  socketsForRapid.set(userUuid, socket)
}
```

**Connection URL:**

```
wss://api.domain.co:3004/socket.io/?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY5N2Q....NMTGMsIMovjR5wcntAdQCO-eg184ZCSQ&EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

**The connection which is working on my own hosting is working perfectly fine:**

```
ws://api.my-statging-server.com:3010/socket.io/?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI....QWkbtn_NWEmlJjQ&EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

**You can notice I am using port numbers the same on which my Node service is running.**

On AWS, I have an EC2 instance with ubuntu, where my node service is running on 3004 and the port is allowed, Proxy_wstunnel module is enabled.